# array values are inserted as 0 in the table

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, insert

I am trying to insert users answers (to the php form) in the database. 
The answers are inserted into table "Answer" which has 4 columns: (Id, userId, qId, answer) where Id is a unique id and qId is the question Id (questions are stored in table "question").

**Problem:** 
This is my code where I try to insert data into database (insertPage1.php):

```
<?php

try{
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=Application;host=localhost;charset=utf8mb4', 'user', 'xxxx');

  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$i = 0;
foreach($_SESSION['post'] as $key => $value) {

         $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO Answer (userId, qId, answer) VALUES (userId = :username, qId = :qId, answer = :answer)');
         $stmt -> execute(array(':username' => $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'], ':qId' => $key, ':answer' => $value));

    echo "$i\n";
        echo "$key\n";
    echo "$value\n";
    $i++;

      }
}
   catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Exception -> ';
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
       }

 ?>
```

and this is the code in page2.php where I check for posted answers in page1:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
   if (is_array($_POST[$key])){
           $_SESSION['post'][$key] = implode("\n", $_POST[$key]);     
             }
           else{
                $_SESSION['post'][$key] = $value;
            }
       }

extract($_SESSION['post']); // Function to extract array.*/
include('insertPage1.php');
?>
<html>
//html for the second page...
</html>
```

and here is the result :|

[image]

but the point is that as it can be seen in the first code "insertPage1.php", I added 3lines (echo) to print the value of $i, $key and $value... although, I see on the $value are presented correctly in the log (i.e, it shows q1, q2, ...), I don't know why they appeared as "0" in the table?!!!

any idea would be highly appreciated,

Comment: why are you doing ` VALUES (userId = :username, qId = :qId, answer = :answer)` instead of just ` VALUES (:username, :qId, :answer)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Fix the obvious sql syntax error.
2. `userId` is the name you gave to your column dont use username you're just going to confuse your self
3. I suggest you use call it `$_SESSION['userId']` and use `session_start()` before using it.
4. No need for Sessions use `$_POST` directly!
5. If a key is an array, don't implode it, loop through it

```
try{
$conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=Application;host=localhost;charset=utf8mb4', 'user', 'xxxx');

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO Answer (userId, qId, answer) VALUES (:userId, :qId, :answer)';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_array($_POST[$key])){
            $stmt->execute(array(':userId' => $_SESSION['userId'], ':qId' => $key, ':answer' => $value));
    }
    else{
        foreach ($_POST[$key] as $sub_key => $sub_value) { 
            $stmt->execute(array(':userId' => $_SESSION['userId'], ':qId' => $sub_key, ':answer' => $sub_value));
        }
    }
}

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Exception -> ';
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

---

**Some debugging tips:**

- `0` is the equivalent to null for int
- use `print_r($_POST)` or `print_r($_SESSION)`
- `error_log` is helpful, use it to log the variables you are inserting

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete explanation and useful tips :) Just It has one problem that is it insert also "submit" as qId and "save and continue" as answer! Do you have any idea how can I get rid of this?!

Answer (score 1):

Correct this statement

```
         $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO Answer (userId, qId, answer) VALUES (userId = :username, qId = :qId, answer = :answer)');
```

to

```
         $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO Answer (userId, qId, answer) VALUES (:username, :qId, :answer)');
```